# how to run a spring boot app in intellij free edition on mac? cant copy files due to com.apple.quarantine

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-initializr

I created a simple spring boot app using the online initializer, downloaded the resultant zip, unzipped it an opened the files in intellij and added some hello world code.  However, I haven't found a way to run it from intellij. I runs fine from command line using "./mvnw spring-boot:run".

The intellij documentation says that you should be able to hit the run arrow next to the main class, but this doesn't work at all. Presumably it only works with paid for version of intellij.

I tried creating a new run configuration with type of "maven", and "spring-boot:run" as the run parameter.

When I run this config, it starts well, but fails with this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) on project kafka1: filtering /Users/xxx/dev/kafka/kafka1/src/main/resources/application.properties to /Users/xxx/dev/kafka/kafka1/target/classes/application.properties failed with MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 -> [Help 1]
```

Basically it cant copy the application.properties file to target/classes.

Looking deeper, all files and directories in source have the "@" attribute set, and doing "xattr -l application.properties" it gives:

```
com.apple.provenance: 
com.apple.quarantine: 0081;65d7b0ba;Chrome;
```

This is set for all files and directories that were downloaded from the spring initalizer.

This is a bit of a show stopper for all users of spring boot initializer and intellij (at least free version)?

Does anyone have a hand script which will traverse the project structure "fixing" the quarantine issue, so that intellij can actually run the project?

Comment: How did you import your project into IntelliJ? While the community edition of IntelliJ doesn't have full Spring support, it definitely has Maven support. So importing the zip file as maven project should give you the maven targets necessary for running the application. Additionally you can set `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven` to be able to build/run your application with the usual buttons in the IDE

Comment: The imported project does show maven tab in intellij, but the "run" buttons on the main metthod nor class work.  I have been trying to create a run configuration by hand, to find a way to run spring boot projects, but its not easy for beginners, and not documented in the tutorials which all say just hut the run button. I dont have the paid version, so cant tell if this is a bug, or its missing from free version.

Comment: You don't need an additional run configuration even in the free version you should be able to just run the main method. If it doesn't you probably imported it in some weird way. Please provide a screenshot of the intellij window.

Comment: To import he file, I used file->new->project from existing sourced and selected the root of the project unpacked from the initializer download.  It does pickup maven stuff, and I can open the maven tab on the right and hit "kafka1->lifecycle->clean" for example, but there is no obvious way to run "spring-boot:run"

Comment: After hitting the "run" button next to the main class or main method, intellj creates a run config.  this run config simply tries to run java 17 with the class,  which obviously fails as its not using maven.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to do the following to the projects root dir:

```
sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine kafka1
sudo xattr -dr com.apple.provenance kafka1
```

Then do "cd kafka1", then "mvn clean", then you can finally use your new intellij run profile to run the app.